# Find And Change Element In a Parsed HTML DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, dom-node

I am getting an HTML string in response to an ajax request. It is a large HTML string with a lot of hierarchical child nodes.

I parse it using

```
jQuery.parseHTML();
```

to convert it into a DOM. Now i want to change the content of a child node with a certain ID and then regenerate the HTML.

The Problem is when ever i use a jQuery method to select a dom element to make the changes, it returns that particular node and the

```
jQuery.html()
```

just changes that node to HTML.

I have tried following code samples

```
 var parsedHTML = jQuery.parseHTML( 'htmlstring' );
 jQuery(parsedHTML).find('#element-id').text('changed text').html();
```

or

```
jQuery(parsedHTML).filter('#element-id').text('changed text').html();
```

the problem is it only returns span#element-id and when html() is applied, the generated html has only span text.

How can i generate back the complete html and change the specific node?

Comment: It would **really** help us answer your question if you showed us the HTML and indicated what the element you wanted to change was.

Comment: I think all day long you have a job of voting down people.. Hard life man. @T.J.Crowder. Spend your time in helping people or get a life.

Comment: It was a 1000 letter html code, i left it out for some reason.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't chain (or if you do, use `end`, but simpler really just not to). By chaining, you're saying you only want the HTML of the last set of elements in the chain:

```
var elements = jQuery(parsedHTML);
elements.filter('#element-id').text('changed text');
var html = elements.html();
```

But `elements.html()` will only give you the **inner** HTML of the first element. To get the full HTML string again, you need to get the **outer** HTML of each element and join them together:

```
var html = elements.map(function() {
  return this.outerHTML;
}).get().join("");
```

Note that your use of `filter` assumes the element is at the top level of the HTML string. If it is, great, that's fine. If it isn't, you'll want `find` instead.

Example with `filter`:

```js
var parsedHTML = jQuery.parseHTML(
  "<span>no change</span>" +
  "<span id='element-id'>change me</span>" +
  "<span>no change</span>"
);
var elements = jQuery(parsedHTML);
elements.filter('#element-id').text('changed text');
console.log(elements.map(function() {
  return this.outerHTML;
}).get().join(""));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Example with `find`:

```js
var parsedHTML = jQuery.parseHTML(
  "<span>no change</span>" +
  "<div>the span is in here<span id='element-id'>change me</span></div>" +
  "<span>no change</span>"
);
var elements = jQuery(parsedHTML);
elements.find('#element-id').text('changed text');
console.log(elements.map(function() {
  return this.outerHTML;
}).get().join(""));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Do we need `filter` ?

Comment: @Rayon: Quite possibly. If the `id="element-id"` element is at the *top level* of the HTML string, that's the way to isolate it. Obviously, if it's nested inside some other element, it would be `find` or similar.

Comment: worked with find.. but jQuery.html() gives me the full html.

Comment: The outerHTML point is quite important.. ANYONE reading this should take care of converting to HTML. I wasted 3 hours on it.